# I am a getting a java.lang.NullPointerException when using the remove(T entity) method for JPA

Tags: java, jpa

kindly help me out with this NullPointerException error i am getting while trying to use the remove(T entity) method in JPA

Here is my code

**ControllerServlet**

```
}else if (userPath.equals("/confirm_delete")){

       String userid = request.getParameter("userToDelete");

       int usrId = Integer.valueOf(userid);

        SystemusersFacade usertoDelete = new SystemusersFacade();

       Systemusers user = new Systemusers();
            user =  systemusersFacade.find(usrId);

       usertoDelete.remove(user);

        userPath ="/view_users";
```

SystemusersFacade extends AbstractFacade that contains the remove(T entity) method)

```
remove(T entity) method
public void remove(T entity) {
        System.out.println(entity);
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }
```

Below is the NullPointerException i am getting

```
Info:   theBankingGuide was successfully deployed in 13,022 milliseconds.
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():ControllerServlet:
Info:   entity.Systemusers[ userId=1 ]
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ControllerServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ControllerServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at session.AbstractFacade.remove(AbstractFacade.java:35)
    at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am sure that the entity is not passed as a null because when i use a System.out.Print, it gives me a value as you see in the log above
**Info:   entity.Systemusers[ userId=1 ]**

I have also checked the debugger and the entity variable exits with the following parameters

```
entity  Systemusers #1232   
Static          
_persistence_cacheKey   HardCacheWeakIdentityMap$ReferenceCacheKey  #1280   
_persistence_fetchGroup     null    
_persistence_href       null    
_persistence_listener   AttributeChangeListener #1281   
_persistence_primaryKey Integer ObjectFieldVariable _persistence_primaryKey 
_persistence_relationshipInfo       null
_persistence_session        null    
_persistence_shouldRefreshFetchGroup    boolean false   
adsCollection   IndirectList    size = 0
mmtransinfoCollection   IndirectList    size = 0
securitiesinfoCollection    IndirectList    size = 0
systemUsersTime  Date  02-Jan-2015 20:09:52
userEmail   String  jonahkayizzi@gmail.com
userId  Integer 1
userName    String  "Jonah"
userPassword    String  "0xgl#kylZ"
userType    String  "Manager"
```

I also tried creating my custome delete function in the SystemusersFacade and i got the same error.

Please help out

**EDIT**

```
package session; 

import entity.Systemusers; 
import javax.ejb.Stateless; 
import javax.persistence.EntityManager; 
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext; 

/** 
* 
* @author Jonah 
*/ 
@Stateless 
public class SystemusersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Systemusers> { 

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "theBankingGuidePU") 
    private EntityManager em; 

    @Override 
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() { 
        return em; 
    } 

    public SystemusersFacade() { 
        super(Systemusers.class); 
    } 
}

package session; 

import java.util.List; 
import javax.persistence.EntityManager; 
import javax.persistence.Query; 

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> { 

    private Class<T> entityClass; 

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) { 
        this.entityClass = entityClass; 
    } 

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager(); 

    public void remove(T entity) { 
        System.out.println(entity);
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity)); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: `getEntityManager()` returns null?

Comment: What does `getEntityManager().merge(entity)` return in your debugger?

Comment: When you do SystemusersFacade usertoDelete = new SystemusersFacade() in your Servlet, how do you suppose that the EntityManager in SystemusersFacade returned by getEntityManager() gets instantiated? Can it be anything other than null?

Comment: @Predrag, getEntityManager().merge(entity) seems to be returning a null in the debugger though entity is not null.

Name        Type                value
entity Systemusers #1858
em                            null

Comment: @AlanHay, how can i get the EntityManager not to be null in this case.

what do i need to instatiate?

Below is the code for the SystemusersFacade
`@Stateless
public class SystemusersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Systemusers> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "theBankingGuidePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public SystemusersFacade() {
        super(Systemusers.class);
    }
   
}`

Sorry, i am sort of new to JPA

Comment: You probably have some configuration error. Post the code of `getEntityManager()`

Comment: @PredragMaric
 `protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }`

Comment: Are you running this on Tomcat?

Comment: Post the code of SystemusersFacade or AbstractFacade. Are you using some kind of container Spring/JEE?

Comment: @PredragMaric,  i am using GlassFish

Comment: @AlanHay, i am using EJB /JEE

I will post the code for both in the comments below

Comment: `package session;

import entity.Systemusers;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Jonah
 */
@Stateless
public class SystemusersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Systemusers> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "theBankingGuidePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public SystemusersFacade() {
        super(Systemusers.class);
    }    
}`

Comment: `package session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
public void remove(T entity) {
        
        System.out.println(entity);
       
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

`SystemusersFacade usertoDelete = new SystemusersFacade()` is your problem (ignoring strange name, maybe a copy/paste error). Since you instantiate it using `new`, you are bypassing container management so the annotations are not processed. You need to inject the bean into the class that uses it. Use something like this

```
@EJB
private SystemusersFacade systemusersFacade;

...

String userid = request.getParameter("userToDelete");
int usrId = Integer.valueOf(userid);
Systemusers user = systemusersFacade.find(usrId);
systemusersFacade.remove(user);
```

Comment: Yes you are right @Predrag,
'SystemusersFacade usertoDelete = new SystemusersFacade()'
was unnecessary and actually the one leading to the NullPointerException.

I just got rid of it and everything is working as expected.
Thanks :)